# Powershel append node

Tags: powershell

I need to add  3 more nodes to a xml document. I'm trying to solve the issu of many ways, but unfortunately with no results
My code is doing the job, but is adding an attribute that i don´t want:
How can do this repeating the node?

```
 My code:

     function Get-XmlNamespaceManager([ xml ]$XmlDocument, [string]$NamespaceURI = "")

 {
     # If a Namespace URI was not given, use the Xml document's default namespace.
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NamespaceURI)) { $NamespaceURI = $XmlDocument.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI }

    # In order for SelectSingleNode() to actually work, we need to use the fully qualified node path along with an Xml Namespace Manager, so set them up.
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager = New-Object  System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($XmlDocument.NameTable)
    $xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)
    return ,$xmlNsManager   # Need to put the comma before the variable name so that PowerShell doesn't convert it into an Object[].
}

  function Get-FullyQualifiedXmlNodePath([string]$NodePath,  [string]$NodeSeparatorCharacter = '.')
  {
    return "/ns:$($NodePath.Replace($($NodeSeparatorCharacter), '/ns:'))"
}

   function Get-XmlNode([ xml ]$XmlDocument, [string]$NodePath, [string]$NamespaceURI = "", [string]$NodeSeparatorCharacter = '.')
     {

      $xmlNsManager = Get-XmlNamespaceManager -XmlDocument $XmlDocument -NamespaceURI $NamespaceURI
[string]$fullyQualifiedNodePath = Get-FullyQualifiedXmlNodePath -NodePath $NodePath -NodeSeparatorCharacter $NodeSeparatorCharacter

   # Try and get the node, then return it. Returns $null if the node was not found.
   $node = $XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode($fullyQualifiedNodePath, $xmlNsManager)
return $node
}

   function Get-XmlNodes([ xml ]$XmlDocument, [string]$NodePath, [string]$NamespaceURI = "", [string]$NodeSeparatorCharacter = '.')
   {
    $xmlNsManager = Get-XmlNamespaceManager -XmlDocument $XmlDocument -NamespaceURI $NamespaceURI
[string]$fullyQualifiedNodePath = Get-FullyQualifiedXmlNodePath -NodePath $NodePath -NodeSeparatorCharacter $NodeSeparatorCharacter

   # Try and get the nodes, then return them. Returns $null if no nodes were found.
   $nodes = $XmlDocument.SelectNodes($fullyQualifiedNodePath, $xmlNsManager)
return $nodes
}


   $XmlDocument = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Scripts\Add_Languages\Source\' -Recurse -Include "*.imdi" -File | ForEach-Object{
   [xml]$Xml = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $Keynodes = Get-XmlNodes $Xml -NodePath  "METATRANSCRIPT.Session.MDGroup.Content.Keys"


     $ref = $Xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.MDGroup.Content.Keys.Key | Where {$_.Name -eq 'Topic'}
     $Key = $Xml.CreateElement('Key')
     $addAtt = $xml.CreateAttribute("Name")
     $addAtt.Value = "Topic"
     $key.Attributes.Append($addAtt)
     $Keynodes.InsertAfter($Key,$ref)


     $ref = $Xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.MDGroup.Content.Keys.Key | Where {$_.Name -eq 'Keyword'}
     $Key = $Xml.CreateElement('Key')
     $addAtt = $xml.CreateAttribute("Name")
     $addAtt.Value = "Keyword"
     $key.Attributes.Append($addAtt)
     $Keynodes.InsertAfter($Key,$ref)

     $xml.Save($_.FullName)
```

}

This is the result of my code:

```
         <Keys>
          <Key Name="Status">Finished</Key>
          <Key Name="Keyword">Language profile, interview, multilingualism, younger speaker</Key>
          <Key Name="Topic">Language profile</Key>
          <Key Name="Topic" xmlns="" /> # <<<<< This node, it's adding the xmlns="" (i don´t need) i  need only <Key Name="Topic"/>
          <Key Name="Location Address">Kabaroan, Babuyan Claro</Key>
      </Keys>
```

I need:

```
      <Keys>
       <Key Name="Status">Finished</Key>
       <Key Name="Keyword">Language profile, interview, multilingualism, younger speaker</Key>
       <Key Name="Topic">Language profile</Key>
       <Key Name="Topic"></Key>
       <Key Name="Topic"></Key>
       <Key Name="Topic"></Key>
       <Key Name="Location Address">Kabaroan, Babuyan Claro</Key>
     </Keys>
```

Thanks again for any help, on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remark is that `$XmlDocument = Get-ChildItem` can returm a number of both `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` **objects**. You should not treat that as the full path **string** of a single item in the folder.

The Path for the xml ends in `.imdi`. Is that the folder name or did you rename the xml file to have the `.imdi` extension?

Next, you are using a function `Get-XmlNodes` I don't have. Is that from some module?

Here is the revised code without using that function, assuming `C:\Scripts\Add_Languages\Source\IVB1-20180808_01.imdi` is not the full path to a single xml file with a strange extension, but the path to a folder where your xml is stored.

```
$path = 'C:\Scripts\Add_Languages\Source\IVB1-20180808_01.imdi'

# get the first XML FileInfo object from this folder
$XmlFile  = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.xml' -File)[0]
[xml]$Xml = Get-Content $XmlFile.FullName -Raw

# the number of new Topic nodes you want to add
$numberOfTopicsToAdd = 3

$Keynodes = $Xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.MDGroup.Content.Keys

# get the first 'Key' childnode with attribute "Name=Topic"
# using XPath:
$refNode  = $Keynodes.SelectSingleNode("//Key[@Name='Topic']")
# or using:
# $refNode = @($Keynodes.ChildNodes | Where-Object {$_.LocalName -eq 'Key' -and $_.Name -eq 'Topic'})[0]

# create the new nodes
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numberOfTopicsToAdd; $i++) {
    $Key = $Xml.CreateElement('Key')
    $addAtt = $Xml.CreateAttribute("Name")
    $addAtt.Value = "Topic"
    [void]$key.Attributes.Append($addAtt)
    [void]$Keynodes.InsertAfter($Key, $refNode)
}

# create a name for the output xml file by prefixing with 'New_'
$outXml = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('New_{0}' -f $XmlFile.Name)
$xml.Save($outXml)
```

Output:

```xml
<Keys>
  <Key Name="Status">Finished</Key>
  <Key Name="Keyword">Language profile, interview, multilingualism, younger speaker</Key>
  <Key Name="Topic">Language profile</Key>
  <Key Name="Topic" />
  <Key Name="Topic" />
  <Key Name="Topic" />
  <Key Name="Location Address">Kabaroan, Babuyan Claro</Key>
</Keys>
```

Hope that helps

---

As per your comment, the path I saw as folder path is in fact the xml file's Full path and name, all you have to do is change the top lines into:

```
# get the content of the XML file
$XmlFile  = Get-Item -Path 'C:\Scripts\Add_Languages\Source\IVB1-20180808_01.imdi'
[xml]$Xml = Get-Content $XmlFile.FullName -Raw
```

The rest of the code can stay unchanged

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks once again for your great help. Sorry, my bad, i forgot to include the function Get-xmlNodes. The imdi file extension, is the original file extension, but it works like an xml. Once again many thanks for your grateful help, and i´m sorry to complicate the thinks excluding part of code! I will update with the full code.

Comment: @Paulo I have added some code for you to change in the original answer. (of course I do this without that function `Get-XmlNodes`)

Comment: yes, i saw it, and i'm working with it. I just update the code to give a better understanding, what have i done, before your help.